# What does the slash mean in this set notation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, clustering

In Section 2.2, Definition 1 of [this paper](https://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tk/2018/06/08240674.pdf), it has the following:

[image]

Here, $x,y \subseteq X $ and $X$ is a set of $d$-dimensional vectors. $dist(x,y)$ stands for the Eucledian distance between $x$ and $y$.

What is the highlighted notation in points $1)$ and $3)$ ? ex: $N \subseteq X/\{x\}$

Can you explain those points in plain English?

Comment: I guess it's set difference

Comment: @Berci that makes sense. Please post that as an answer. BTW, I haven't seen this used anywhere to denote set difference - maybe it's just me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It (probably, I can't access the full text of the paper) means "without". So $X \setminus \{x \}$ means "the set $X$ without the point $x$", but usually the backslash is used for that. The LaTeX command for the slash is "\setminus". It could also be quotient, for example used for groups, then $N / G$ means "$N$ modulo $G$".

Comment: Yes, it means "without."  Interpreting it this way is consistent with k-nearest neighbors as I know it.  Read this way, the three clauses simply mean, "(1) The $k$ nearest neighbors are drawn from the original set but (of course) can't include the set itself. (2) There are $k$ nearest neighbors and (3) All the other points (beyond the given point and its k nearest neighbors) are farther away than these k nearest neighbors (or equally distant)."  I can't imagine that it could possibly mean anything else, regardless of what the rest of the paper says.

Answer (score 4):

Without more context I would assume that the writer used the forward slash '/' instead of the more conventional backward slash '\' to denote set difference.
Thus $A / B$ would denote the set of elements of $A$ which are not in $B$.

The first line then translates as "$N$ is the set made up of the elements of $X$ distinct from $x$" while the third translates as "Given any element $y$ of $N$ and any vector $z$ of $X$ which cannot be written as the sum of an element of $N$ and $x$, the distance between $x$ and $y$ is less than or equal that one between $x$ and $z$".

Answer (score 3):

More formally, $S \setminus \{a\} := \{ x \in S \mid x \ne a \}$.