# Set of complex numbers notation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, notation

What is the meaning of the notation $\mathbb{C}^\times$ where  $\mathbb{C}$ is the usual set of complex numbers? The context is that of continuous functions of the torus $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ that are  $\mathbb{C}^\times$-valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, that is, the set of non-zero complex numbers.

Comment: Likely many readers will be just as perplexed as to the the meaning of the [slashed set difference notation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132713/what-does-the-slash-mean-in-this-set-notation)

Answer (score 4):

The notation $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is the multiplicative group consisting of all of the nonzero elements of $\mathbb{C}$.  That is, $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is the *set* $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, along with the *operation* of complex multiplication.  This suggests somewhat more structure than just the notation $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ alone.

More generally, a field is a tuple $(k,+,\times)$ consisting of a set $k$ and two binary operations which have the following properties:

1. the addition operation $+$ is commutative and associative,
2. there is an additive identity $0\in k$ such that $x + 0 = x = 0 + x$ for all $x \in k$,
3. additive inverses exist: if $x \in k$, then there is some $-x \in k$ such that $x+(-x) = 0$
4. the multiplication operation $\times$ is commutative and associative,
5. there is a multiplicative identity $1\in k$ such that $x\times 1 = x = 1\times x$ for all $x \in k$;
6. multiplicative inverses exist:  if $x \in k$ and $x \ne 0$, then there is some $x^{-1} \in k$ such that $x \times x^{-1} = 1$; and
7. multiplication distributes over addition; that is, if $x,y,z \in k$, then $x\times (y+z) = (x\times y) + (x\times z)$.

Properties 1–3 can be reduced to the statement "$(k,+)$ is an abelian group", while properties 4–6 can be restated as "$(k\setminus\{0\}, \times)$ is an abelian group".  The last property is a compatibility condition—that is, the two operations need to be compatible in the manner indicated.  As the multiplicative group appears with some frequency, it is useful to have a succinct notation for it.  The usual convention it to write
$$ k^\times = (k\setminus\{0\}, \times). $$
Again, it is worth noting that the notation indicates both a set (i.e. the set of nonzero elements of $k$), as well as an algebraic structure on that set (the multiplication operation).

Comment: To the person who is repeatedly upvoting and downvoting:  is there something that I can do to improve this answer?